# Why can't I write asynchronous code like this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want to execute some JavaScript repeatedly until I get a response from the server. In this simplified version of the problem, I want "Out!" to be printed to the console when the response is returned and after myFunction has stopped executing, but for some reason, the while loop is never terminated, and the "out" variable never gets set to true. What am I doing wrong here?

```
let keepGoing = true;   
let out = false;


function myFunction() {
    if (keepGoing) {
        console.log('Still going!');
        setTimeout(myFunction, 100);
    }
    else {
        out = true;
    }
}

setTimeout(myFunction, 100);

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then((response) => {
       keepGoing = false;
       while (!out);
       console.log('Out!');
    });
```

Comment: Remove the `while(!out);`. The whole `.then` callback only executes when the response is returned. There is no need for any more waiting.

Comment: Additionally, because of the event loop's behaviour, JS can execute only one piece of (even async) code at the same time

Comment: Should've been more specific in the question. I also want to ensure that myFunction has finished executing, and I need some way of verifying that.

Comment: Using Promises, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is a single-threaded language. This means that only one statement can ever be executed at a time. When you have something like `while (!out);`, this *by necessity* will block all execution and will never continue to the next statement.

Callbacks and Promises are solutions to this problem that allow different portions of code to be executed out of sequence, but still, the underlying engine is single-threaded. So when you say,

> I also want to ensure that myFunction has finished executing.

You need to understand that there is no way for any other portion of code to execute if `myFunction` is currently executing. Think about this the other way around: what you want instead is to ensure that `myFunction` doesn't execute after the response is received.

Here's an alternative solution:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('Still going!');
}

const intervalId = setInterval(myFunction, 100);

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then((response) => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    console.log('Out!');
  });
```

How it works: `myFunction` will be executed every ~100 ms until the response is returned in `then`, at which point the interval will be canceled (it won't be executed on the next 100 ms interval), and `Out!` is logged.